# Prevent reloading certain parts of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm fairly new to web development so I don't have much experience with any of this. I currently have a navbar at the top of my website (made with Foundation), but I don't want it to reload every time the page reloads. I've noticed on several websites that certain parts of the page are kept in place when links are clicked and the url changes. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What you want to achieve can be done with AJAX. With this technique you can use JavaScript to load external contents into your page without reloading it.

Comment: Usually the modern way to do that is using AJAX and only loading the parts that need to change. But that's a vast topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this. Using AJAX calls is one of them, iframe another. You could even create a one page application and show/hide elements when certain buttons are clicked. This will however force you to load all the data at once so I won't recommend that (depending on the website).

A small article about how you can use the [iframe](http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/a/aaiframe.htm)  option.

A small article about the [AJAX](https://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/)  option, they include a small demo to show how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an `<iframe>` in your code and have the links in your nav target it.  When you click on a link, the `<iframe>` will load the new content, but the rest of your page will not change.